# Backbone rendering view but only in Chrome

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, requirejs, fetch

I'm a beginer in Backbone, so this is a very simple example  rendering a simple template.
and I have a problem with rendering this template. It works only in Chrome. 
When I debuged this code  after 'this.collection.fetch()' in MasterView object is empty but in Chrome has a my collection. I don't know why it works in Chrome but not in other browsers.

**index.html**

```
    <div class="Presentation">

    </div>

    <script id="slideTemplate" type="text/template">
        <h1><%=slide_title %></h1>
        <h2><%=slide_subheading %></h2>
        <div> <%=content %> </div>
    </script>
```

**Model**

```
define(['backbone','underscore'],function(Backbone,_){
var linkModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
                    slide_title: "slide", 
        slide_subheading: "sub slide 1",
        content: "bla bla bla"
         }
     });

return linkModel;
    });
```

**Collection**

```
define(['backbone','underscore','models/link','libs/backbone-localstorage'],function(Backbone,_,link,storage){
var linkModels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: link,
    localStorage: new storage('links')

});

return linkModels;
    });
```

**SingleView**

```
define(['jquery','backbone','underscore'],function($,Backbone,_){
var linkView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "article",
    className: "slide-container",
    template: $("#slideTemplate").html(),
    render: function(){
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

return linkView;
    });
```

**MasterView**

```
define(['jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'collections/links',
    'views/linkView', 'views/data'], function($, Backbone,_,links,linksView,data){
var favsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".Presentation"),
    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.collection = new links(slides);    
        _.bindAll(this, 'renderLink', 'renderAll');         

              this.collection.fetch();
      this.renderAll();
    },
    renderAll: function(){
        this.collection.each(
            this.renderLink
        );
    },
    renderLink: function(model){
        var view = new linksView({model: model});
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        model.save();
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("Ready...");
    }
});

return new favsView;
  });
```

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I don't know how all this project create in jsfiddle, because I use a few libraries for example requirejs. But I deleted this line: this.collection.fetch(), and now it works in other browsers too.  
When I find out what was the cause of my problem I will write :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple "**A** in **AJAX** stands for **Asynchronous**" problem right here:

```
  this.collection.fetch();
  this.renderAll();
```

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is an AJAX call so there's no guarantee that you'll have anything in your collection when `renderAll` is executed.

The recommended (at *my* recommended) approach is to do two things:

1. Bind your view's `render` method to the collection's `"reset"` event. This will trigger a `render` call when the collection is fetched from the server.
2. Modify your `render` and template to do something sensible with an empty collection. You can display a *Loading...* message, say *No items*, or whatever.

Your code should look more like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    // Always do this first to be sure that your function
    // references refer to the right things.
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderLink');

    this.collection = new links(slides);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.render(); // If you must.
},
render: function() {
    // And update your template to with a "loading..." message
    // of some sort...
    this.collection.each(this.renderLink);
    return this; // A good convention.
},
renderLink: function(model) {
    var view = new linksView({model: model});
    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
}
```

The [`render`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render) method is for rendering, don't overcomplicate things by introducing a `renderAll` that does `render`s job. Also, calling `model.save()` inside your `renderLink` is a bit odd, the models should already be on the server since they just came from `fetch` and normally you'd put the `save` call beside some action that updated the model in response to a user event.